# Can't save updated XML content

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm wanting to update the XML content within an XML node (node is called `<i_url>` with a new URL given to it.

It does not seem to set it though. When I step through the debugger, it seems I have reference to this node `<i_url>` and then when I set it with a new string and call `nodeToUpdate` I can see the new value in there.

It's not persisting to the XML file though, which I was wanting to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$nodeToUpdate = $node.SelectSingleNode("//i_url");
$url = "http://www.daniel.co.nz"
$nodeToUpdate.innertext = $url;
#if i check nodeToUpdate it's got new value
```

Comment: I don't see any code that even remotely looks like saving XML... Probably you forgot to paste whole sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [doc.save(filePath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't save the XML anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Ie.

```
$path = 'C:\Temp\config.xml'
$XML  = [XML] (Get-Content $path)

$ServerName = 'Google'
$URL  = 'http:\\www.google.se'

$UpdateURL = $XML.Config.Server.URL
$UpdateURL.Name = $URL

$UpdateServerName = $XML.Config.Server.ServerName
$UpdateServerName.Name = $ServerName

$XML.Save($path)
```

Ran on this 'XML' ...

```
<Config>
  <Server>
    <ServerName Name="BBC" />
    <URL Name="http:\\bbc.co.uk" />
  </Server>
</Config>
```